# How to properly extract parameters from Websocket in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I have this code :

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://localhost:3000?url=${myRef.current.value}&quality=highest quality`)
```

Which sends a query to Websocket server and I can get the URL by :

```
wss.on('connection', (ws , req , client) => {
    console.log('this is direct ws ' , req.url)
})
```

The `req.url` comes back as

```
?url=https://localhost/listen?value=3k2k33f4&quality=highest%20quality
```

Now to make use of this url I need to extract letters from the string apparently and this is troublesome and time-taking.

Is there a better way or conventional method I can use to get parameters from url query in Websocket so I don't have to deal with `%20` and extra `?`

Comment: is it not in `req.query.quality`? besides, you can use inbuilt [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'quality' of undefined so I don't think so.